# Is there a Rails function or a gem to display all the controllers and actions a user went through before displaying the result page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

It is for educational purpose. At the moment I am using `%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>` to display very basic information like the action, the controller, the id, etc. that were called after I clicked on a link.

I'd like to know if it's possible to have the same kind of debug information, but to display the succession of requests and action, etc. Rails went through before displaying the result on the page. It would help me to understand more deeply Rails framework.

Comment: Isn't "succession of requests and actions Rails went through before displaying the result on the page" exactly what you would see in the log file?  For debugging purposes I'll often wrap controller before filters to make it clearer what is being hit during a request.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of like a log, except it's more synthetical, displaying classes called and parameters the parameters they took, etc. Sorry if it's confusing, but I know there's a plug-in for PHP that does just that, except I don't know its name...

Comment: What you're talking about in your comment is *very* different from what you ask in your question. Getting the controller and action is very different than profiling every method call.

Comment: Yes you're right, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to display the log/development.log using the command **tail** and filter it using **grep**:

```
tail log/development.log -f | grep Processing -A 2
```

the parameter '-A' (after) is to show 2 lines that usually contain the params, you can change it as you prefer or use '-B' (before) or use a regexp in grep to filter exactly what you need,

I hope this can help you.

Ale